# JAXB unmarshal wrapped list

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Is it possible to directly unmarshal a list of wrapped elements into a `List<String>` in JAXB?

For example I have a XML like:

```
<TEST>

  <MIME_INFO>
      <MIME>
        <MIME_SOURCE>foo.png</MIME_SOURCE>
        <MIME_PURPOSE>normal</MIME_PURPOSE>
      </MIME>
      <MIME>
        <MIME_SOURCE>bar.png</MIME_SOURCE>
        <MIME_PURPOSE>normal</MIME_PURPOSE>
      </MIME>
  </MIME_INFO>

</TEST>
```

So would it be possible to directly unmarshal this XML file into a `List<String>` only containing { "foo.png", "bar.png" }?

I know that you could create a class hierarchy with the correct annotations to perform this unmarshalling but i would like to have a code like:

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "TEST")
@XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Info {

    // -> what annotation to put here?
    private List<String> infos;

    public List<String> getInfos() {
        return infos;
    }

}
```

And the main file:

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class UnmarshallingJAXB {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {

        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Info.class);
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

        Info info = (Info) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("test.xml"));

        // should output foo.png and bar.png
        info.getInfos().forEach(System.out::println);

    }   
}
```

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: The intended usaged for JAXB is to unmarshal the whole XML into an object structure. Your use case can better be fulfilled by using XPATH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies for answering so late, but this is the first hit on Google if search for related problems so it might help anyway.

Yes, it is possible, using

```
@XmlElementWrapper
```

in combination

```
@XmlElement
```

See [this example](https://howtodoinjava.com/jaxb/xmlelementwrapper-annotation/) for more detailed info.